# The Derivative as a Matrix of Partial Derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:R^n \times R^n \to R$ be defined by $f(x,y)=x\cdot y$.

(i) Show that f is differentiable on $R^n \times R^n$.

(ii) Show that $Df(a,b)(x,y) = a\cdot y+b\cdot x$.

My idea is to use chain rule. Say $u:R^n \to R$ and $u(x_1, \ldots, x_n)=x$ and $w:R^n \to R$ and $w(y_1, \ldots, y_n)=y$. Then $Df = Dw\cdot Du$ and $D_1f=D_1w\cdot D_1u$.

However, I have been stuck here because I do not know how to get the derivative of $u$. If I am on the wrong track, then I think we may use the definition of differentiability to prove it. But how?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the derivative of $f$ at a point $(a,b)$ is the *unique* linear map $Df(a,b) : \Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ such that the following limit is $0$:
$$
\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b)-Df(a,b)(h,k)}{|(h,k)|}.
$$
Expanding this out:
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{(a\cdot b + a\cdot k + b\cdot h + h\cdot k)-a\cdot b-Df(a,b)(h,k)}{|(h,k)|} \\
=&\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{a\cdot k + b\cdot h + h\cdot k-Df(a,b)(h,k)}{|(h,k)|}. \\
&= \lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{h\cdot k}{|(h,k)|} + \lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{a\cdot k + b\cdot h - Df(a,b)(h,k)}{|(h,k)|}
\end{align*}
Check that the first term is in fact $0$. Then, since the linear map $Df(a,b)$ defined by $Df(a,b)(h,k) = a\cdot k + b\cdot h$ certainly makes the second term $0$, by uniqueness, it must be that
$$
Df(a,b)(h,k) = a\cdot k + b\cdot h.
$$

---

To see that the first term really is $0$, use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
h\cdot k \le |h\cdot k| \le |h|\cdot|k| \le\begin{cases} |h|^2 & \text{if $|k|\le |h|$}, \\ |k|^2 & \text{if $|h|\le|k|$.}\end{cases},
$$
so that $h\cdot k$ is certainly less than or equal to $|h|^2 + |k|^2$. Now the denominator is in fact equal to $\sqrt{|h|^2 + |k|^2}$, so that
$$
\bigg|\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)} \frac{h\cdot k}{|(h,k)|}\bigg| \le \lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{|h|^2+|k|^2}{\sqrt{|h|^2+|k|^2}} = \lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\sqrt{|h|^2+|k|^2} = 0,
$$
as desired.